# Clear/remove all GRANT and DENY of a user in SQL

Tags: sql, permissions, sql-grant

I see a lot of `GRANT` and `DENY` records in table `sys.database_permissions` for a specific user.

How can I delete/clear all these entries?
I need to clear to run a script that will do the appropriate `GRANT` and `DENY`.

I can't simply delete the user and recreate. This view does not accept modifications, can't simply run a `DELETE`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no better way than doing it manually:

```
DECLARE cursor_roles CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT dbrole.name as role_name, dbuser.name as user_name
    FROM sys.database_role_members rm
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dbrole ON  dbrole.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dbuser ON  dbuser.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
    WHERE dbuser.name in (@MYUSER)

OPEN cursor_roles
DECLARE @role_name nvarchar(100), @user_name_in_role nvarchar(100)
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_roles INTO @role_name, @user_name_in_role
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    EXEC('ALTER ROLE ' + @role_name + ' DROP MEMBER ' + @user_name_in_role)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_roles INTO @role_name, @user_name_in_role
END

CLOSE cursor_roles  
DEALLOCATE cursor_roles
```